# IE8 CSS float doesn't wrap at edge of screen, instead it stays on same line

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-float

**EDIT: I've got confused please close this question**

I would expect floated divs to wrap when they hit the edge of the screen, and they do in all browsers, except IE8. In IE8 only, the divs extend to the right infinitly, and a horizontal scrollbar is created.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="float:left;height:290px;width:250px;">
(some text)
</div>

<div style="float:left;height:290px;width:250px;">
(some text)
</div>

<div style="float:left;height:290px;width:250px;">
(some text)
</div>

...etc
```

Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: could you post your code with css in a **http://jsfiddle.net/**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe wrap a div around it? What surrounds these div's you created is kind of important.

Cause rendered in jsfiddle in IE8 it won't show a problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/sYskU/